# A break at the end of a function

Tags: python-3.x

I was assigned to complete the task:

1. "Inside of the function, I need a *for* loop that prints each thing in items."

> ```
> def loopy(items):
>     for new_item in items:
>         print(item)
> ```

(I filled in the last two lines and it was correct.)

2. "Forgot that I need to *break* out of the loop when the current item is the string "STOP"."

> ```
> def loopy(items):
>       for new_item in items:
>           print(item)
>       if new_item == "STOP":
>            break
> ```

(This wasn't. But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.)

How do I fix this???

Comment: step 1 was correct? I expected you would need `for new_item in items:
        print(new_item)`

Comment: Your `"STOP"` check and `break` are outside the loop.

Comment: the line `if new_item == "STOP":` may need to be further indented to align with the previous line's `print`, then similarly further indent the `break`

Comment: You also may want to check if you `break` before the `"STOP"` depending on if you want the stop to print.

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` statement must be inside the loop.

```
def loopy(items):
      for new_item in items:
          print(item)
          if new_item == "STOP":
               break
```

That way it checks each value of `new_item` not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def loopy(items):
for new_item in items:
    if new_item == "STOP":
        break
    print(new_item)
```

Check for "STOP" before the item is printed